# Why isn't setText updating the JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, settext

I've checked on the other threads here and haven't found a solution.

1) The JFrame is setVisible(true).

2) What does this mean: "I wonder if your problem is a concurrency issue, that you are doing a long-running process on the Swing event thread and that this is preventing your label from updating its text." I read that somewhere else.

3) I haven't initialized multiple times the JPanel that contains the label.

EDIT:
4) updateTurn is called from the JPanel that contains `TrackingPanel` (i.e. `gamePanel`). I call the method `changeTurns();` and here's the code for that:

```
public void changeTurns() {
    if(turnPlayer == playerX)
        turnPlayer = playerO;
    else
        turnPlayer = playerX;

    trackingPanel.updateTurn();
}
```

Here's the relevant code in full:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TrackingPanel extends JPanel{

    /*TURN STUFF*/
    private JPanel turnPanel; //turns panel to keep track of whose turn it is
    private JLabel turnLabel;
    private String turn;

    /*OTHER*/
    private GamePanel gamePanel;


    public TrackingPanel( GamePanel gamePan ) {

        setLayout( new GridLayout(1,4) );
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2,2,4,2,Color.BLACK));

        gamePanel = gamePan;

        /*THIS PANEL DISPLAYS THE TEXT*/
        turnPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(2,1) );
        turn = gamePanel.getPlayerTurn().getLetter();
        turnLabel = new JLabel("      Player " + turn + "'s turn");
        add( turnPanel);

    }//end constructor

    /*THIS IS WHERE THINGS GO WRONG*/
    public void updateTurn() {

        turn = gamePanel.getPlayerTurn().getLetter();
        turnLabel.setText( "      Player" + turn + "'s turn" );
        System.out.println(turn);
    }
}
```

Before `updateTurn()` is called, `turnLabel` says "PlayerX's turn". After, it should say "PlayerO's turn". By printing out `turn` (I get the string 'O', instead of 'X'), I know that whats being displayed ("PlayerX's turn") is not what should be displayed ("PlayerO's turn").

Thanks in advance you smartypants!

EDIT. Tried giving SSCCE but don't know how to include image files. Sorry!

Comment: where do you call updateTurn() ?

Comment: What happens when you try adding a call to `validate` after adding the label?

Comment: do i just write `validate()` write after adding the label? If so, nothing happened. Also, I should note that the JLabel shouldn't have to be added. setText() should just change the text for the current JLabel. I took out the second panel.add(JLabel) call in the question above.

Comment: You should create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org), a minimal compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem but does just that and no more, so we can test the code for ourselves and help you find the problem. Otherwise we're forced to make wild guesses.

Comment: That seems like so much work because I have hundreds of lines of code and I'm not sure what's relevant here. I'll work on it

Comment: @Alex: if you're not sure what's relevant, then we sure as shoot aren't sure either. If you don't get a solution soon, please give it a try as it's a worthwhile exercise. As you progress in your coding education you'll find that you'll make more of these sscce's anyway -- you'll be making more (almost all) classes that are testable in isolation, and then will be testing them before adding them to any larger complex program.

Comment: Your code link is not an [sscce](http://sscce.org) as it does not compile for us without modification, it uses resources not available to us including images, and  it has a lot of code not related to the problem at hand. The problem with this is that means that we have to go through a lot of code that has no bearing on the problem making it tougher for us to understand the problem, and to help you fix it. Please understand that we are volunteers with limited time available with which to help. To create a useful sscce requires a bit of effort in paring out the code that is not needed.

Comment: sorry I took out hundreds of lines of code. I wanted to make sure it was compilable and runnable, which requires including some of the other pieces of code. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make an SSCCE thats compilable and has the images and things.

Comment: Also your code doesn't even add the tracking JLabel to anything displayed in the GUI. Even if I can get your code to work (and with some effort, it's running), I don't see the JLabel anywhere because it's not added to anything. also, don't include images, but instead make your sscce run *without* images. Just show the letter's text by setting the JButton's text not its icon.

Comment: I accidentally removed the line adding the label to the JPanel. IT does do that. You're right about the images bit. So what do I do to make it automatically compilable?

Comment: Start with the code I've posted. Consider placing that code in a different package and running it. You'll see that the label changes text.

Comment: I didn't see the code you posted but the SSCCE was a great idea. I figured it out just by working backwards. It was due to the paintComponent and some silly thing I had seen somewhere.

Comment: The code I posted is in my answer below. Shoot, I posted it 2 hours ago. 1/2 hour of my life,.... gone.

Answer (score 7):

Try using this:

```
 private void setText(final JLabel label, final String text){
    label.setText(text);
    label.paintImmediately(label.getVisibleRect());
 }
```

Comment: no, definitely not needed - plus it can have disastrous effects if called off the EDT

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed it, since I was immediately running a hanging function after it.

Comment: What is reason for using paintImmediately

Comment: This actually worked for me! I needed to update a label showing the current filename which my program was processing. It does the job, without any side effects!

Answer (score 3):

I would make sure that your method updateTurn() calls its code within Swing's thread using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()) method.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with that method. I see that it's supposed to be included in the main() method, but what do I put inside the SwingUtilities method?

Comment: The setText part should be placed in there, this will assure you that updating a Swing component will be done in the right thread.

Answer (score 2):

I've changed your code so that it doesn't require images, and now the turnLabel has been added. It is still too big, but it runs and shows some behaviors:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("MyGame");

      gameFrame.setResizable(false);
      gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      gameFrame.add(new GamePanel());
      gameFrame.pack();
      gameFrame.setVisible(true);

   }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

   private BoardPanel boardPanel; // comprised of 9 mini panels
   /* RELEVANT */
   private static TrackingPanel trackingPanel; // keeps track of score, turn,
                                               // and stuff
   private static Player playerX, playerO, turnPlayer;
   private ArrayList<MiniGame> miniGames;
   private Graphics graphics;
   private Graphics2D graphics2D;

   // constructor
   public GamePanel() {

      super(new BorderLayout());
      setFocusable(true);

      // create 2 new players, and make it X's turn
      playerX = new Player(true, "X");
      turnPlayer = playerX;
      playerO = new Player(true, "O");

      // create tracking panel that will keep track of turns and stuff
      trackingPanel = new TrackingPanel(this);
      trackingPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red)); //!!
      System.out.println("line border added");

      // create panel that will hold the 9 mini games
      boardPanel = new BoardPanel(this);

      // add actionListeners to each button
      miniGames = boardPanel.getMiniGames();
      for (MiniGame mini : miniGames) {
         for (SquareButton button : mini.getSquares())
            button.addActionListener(this);
      }

      // add the tracking and board panels
      add(trackingPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }// end constructor

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      // loop through mini games
      miniGameLoop: for (int gameNum = 0; gameNum < 9; gameNum++) {
         MiniGame mini = miniGames.get(gameNum);
         SquareButton[] buttons = mini.getSquares();

         // loop through buttons of each mini game
         for (int buttonNum = 0; buttonNum < 9; buttonNum++) {
            SquareButton button = buttons[buttonNum];

            // if user clicked on one of the squares on the board
            if (e.getSource() == button) {

               // if the space isn't already taken
               if (button.isEmpty()) {

                  //  mark the space with the player's letter
                  // !! removed
                  // ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                  // "/Images/" + turnPlayer.getLetter() + ".PNG"));
                  // button.setIcon(icon);
                  button.setText(turnPlayer.getLetter()); //!! added
                  button.setEmpty(false);

                  // change turns
                  changeTurns();

                  // exit loops
                  break miniGameLoop;
               }
            }
         }// end loop through squares
      }// end loop through minigames
   }// end actionPerformed method

   public static Player getPlayer(String letter) {
      if (letter == "X")
         return playerX;
      else
         return playerO;
   }

   public Player getPlayerTurn() {
      return turnPlayer;
   }

   public TrackingPanel getTrackingPanel() {
      return trackingPanel;
   }

   /* RELEVANT */
   public void changeTurns() {
      if (turnPlayer == playerX)
         turnPlayer = playerO;
      else
         turnPlayer = playerX;

      trackingPanel.updateTurn();
   }
}// end class GamePanel

class BoardPanel extends JPanel {

   private ArrayList<MiniGame> miniGames;

   // constructs main panel and places all 9 mini games inside
   public BoardPanel(GamePanel gp) {
      super(new GridLayout(3, 3));

      // add miniGames to arrayList
      miniGames = new ArrayList<MiniGame>(9);
      for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
         miniGames.add(new MiniGame(gp, i));

      // add minigames to board
      for (MiniGame mini : miniGames)
         add(mini);
   }

   public void reset() {
      for (MiniGame mini : miniGames)
         mini.clear();
   }

   public ArrayList<MiniGame> getMiniGames() {
      return miniGames;
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TrackingPanel extends JPanel {

   /* TURN STUFF */
   private JPanel turnPanel; // turns panel to keep track of whose turn it is
   private JLabel turnLabel;
   private String turn;

   /* OTHER */
   private GamePanel gamePanel;

   public TrackingPanel(GamePanel gamePan) {

      setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 4, 2, Color.BLACK));

      gamePanel = gamePan;

      /* THIS PANEL DISPLAYS THE TEXT */
      turnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
      turn = gamePanel.getPlayerTurn().getLetter();
      turnLabel = new JLabel("      Player " + turn + "'s turn");
      turnPanel.add(turnLabel);
      add(turnPanel);

   }// end constructor

   /* THIS IS WHERE THINGS GO WRONG */
   public void updateTurn() {

      turn = gamePanel.getPlayerTurn().getLetter();
      turnLabel.setText("      Player" + turn + "'s turn");
      System.out.println(turn);
   }
}

class MiniGame extends JPanel {

   private SquareButton[] squares;
   private SquareButton[] line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7,
         line8;
   private ArrayList<SquareButton[]> lines;
   private int ThreeinARowButtonCount;
   private int panelNum;
   private TrackingPanel trackingPanel;
   private int[] winningLine;
   private Player winner;
   private boolean gameIsOver;
   private Image gameOverIcon;

   public MiniGame(GamePanel gp, int num) {

      // setlayout of the mini games
      super(new GridLayout(3, 3));
      setFocusable(true);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220, 220));

      // setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
      trackingPanel = gp.getTrackingPanel();
      panelNum = num;

      if (panelNum == 1)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 2, Color.BLACK));
      else if (panelNum == 2)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 2, 2, 2, Color.BLACK));
      else if (panelNum == 3)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 2, 2, 0, Color.BLACK));
      else if (panelNum == 4)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 0, 2, 2, Color.BLACK));
      else if (panelNum == 5)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, Color.BLACK));
      else if (panelNum == 6)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 0, Color.BLACK));
      else if (panelNum == 7)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 0, 0, 2, Color.BLACK));
      else if (panelNum == 8)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 0, 2, Color.BLACK));
      else
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 0, 0, Color.BLACK));

      // create list of buttons (each square)
      squares = new SquareButton[9];

      // create squares and add squares to mini game
      for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
         squares[i] = new SquareButton(i);
         add(squares[i]);
      }
   }// end constructor

   public void clear() {
      // TODO this method was not present!!!!! Trying to reconstruct it

   }

   public int getPanelNum() {
      return panelNum;
   }

   public SquareButton[] getSquares() {
      return squares;
   }

   public boolean isOver() {
      return gameIsOver;
   }
}

class SquareButton extends JButton {

   private boolean empty;
   private String letter;
   private int squareNum;

   public SquareButton(int num) {
      empty = true;
      squareNum = num;

      if (num == 0)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
      else if (num == 1)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
      else if (num == 2)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
      else if (num == 3)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
      else if (num == 4)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
      else if (num == 5)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
      else if (num == 6)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 1, Color.BLACK));
      else if (num == 7)
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 0, 1, Color.BLACK));
      else
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK));

   }

   public String getLetter() {
      return letter;
   }

   public boolean isEmpty() {
      return empty;
   }

   public void setEmpty(boolean em) {
      empty = em;
   }

   public int getSquareNum() {
      return squareNum;
   }
}

class Player {

   private boolean human; // indicates if player is human or cpu
   private int score;
   private String letter;

   // constructor
   public Player(boolean hum, String let) {

      // player is human or computer
      human = hum;
      letter = let;
   }

   /* PLAYER METHODS */
   public boolean isHuman() {
      return human;
   }

   public void setHuman(boolean h) {
      human = h;
   }

   public String getLetter() {
      return letter;
   }
}
```

But interestingly, the turnLabel changes its text as it is supposed to in this example above. So now you must try to isolate your error as it may be in code left out. Perhaps it has something to do with concurrency as you mention in your question:

> 2) What does this mean: "I wonder if your problem is a concurrency issue, that you are doing a long-running process on the Swing event thread and that this is preventing your label from updating its text." I read that somewhere else.

So perhaps you have a long running process that you've not shown us in the code above.

Also, your code has an over-use of static fields anti-pattern. Most of the fields that are static should *not* be static.