# JLabel's setText() is not working when called outside of the class that created it

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Can a setText() operation of a JLabel be called outside a JPanel ou the class that created it? Because i have to change my JLabel on a Singleton i created. When i use the setText() function, the text attribute of the JLabel is changed(i can see it from debug), but visually it is still the same old text.

But when i change the text from inside the JPanel that created the JLabel, it works... But i don't want this. I have to make setText() work outside of a JPanel. I am calling it from a Singleton which is created inside the JPanel construction.

The class that contains my JLabel is TelaPrincipal. And on it´s constructor, i change the text of the JLabel via a "setText()" and it workds just fine:

```
public TelaPrincipal() {
        setTitle("codefont2file");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 650, 400);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{12, 92, 42, 42, 92};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.2, 1.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE, 0.0};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        JLabel TituloTela = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createTitle("CodeFont 2 File");
        TituloTela.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        TituloTela.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_TituloTela = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_TituloTela.gridwidth = 7;
        gbc_TituloTela.gridheight = 1;
        gbc_TituloTela.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_TituloTela.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gbc_TituloTela.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_TituloTela.gridx = 0;
        gbc_TituloTela.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(TituloTela, gbc_TituloTela);

        JLabel descricao_software = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createLabel("Bem vindo ao Codefont2File! Escolha seu projeto que converteremos");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_descricao_software = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_descricao_software.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_descricao_software.gridx = 0;
        gbc_descricao_software.gridy = 1;
        gbc_descricao_software.gridwidth = 8;
        gbc_descricao_software.gridheight = 1;
        contentPane.add(descricao_software, gbc_descricao_software);

        JLabel descricao_software2 = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createLabel("o c\u00F3digo fonte para um \u00FAnico PDF!");
        descricao_software2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_descricao_software2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_descricao_software2.gridwidth = 8;
        gbc_descricao_software2.gridheight = 1;
        gbc_descricao_software2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_descricao_software2.gridx = 0;
        gbc_descricao_software2.gridy = 2;
        contentPane.add(descricao_software2, gbc_descricao_software2);

        JLabel lblTtulo = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createLabel("T\u00EDtulo:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblTtulo = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblTtulo.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_lblTtulo.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblTtulo.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblTtulo.gridy = 3;
        contentPane.add(lblTtulo, gbc_lblTtulo);

        campo_nome_projeto = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_campo_nome_projeto = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_campo_nome_projeto.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_campo_nome_projeto.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_campo_nome_projeto.gridx = 1;
        gbc_campo_nome_projeto.gridy = 3;
        contentPane.add(campo_nome_projeto, gbc_campo_nome_projeto);
        campo_nome_projeto.setColumns(10);

        JButton botaoHintNomeProjeto = new JButton("?");
        botaoHintNomeProjeto.setToolTipText("Nome do seu projeto");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_botaoHintNomeProjeto = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_botaoHintNomeProjeto.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_botaoHintNomeProjeto.gridx = 2;
        gbc_botaoHintNomeProjeto.gridy = 3;
        contentPane.add(botaoHintNomeProjeto, gbc_botaoHintNomeProjeto);

        JLabel label_diretorio = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createLabel("Diret\u00F3rio:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label_diretorio = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label_diretorio.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_label_diretorio.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_label_diretorio.gridx = 0;
        gbc_label_diretorio.gridy = 4;
        gbc_label_diretorio.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc_label_diretorio.gridheight = 1;
        contentPane.add(label_diretorio, gbc_label_diretorio);

        campo_preencher_diretorio = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_campo_preencher_diretorio = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_campo_preencher_diretorio.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_campo_preencher_diretorio.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_campo_preencher_diretorio.gridx = 1;
        gbc_campo_preencher_diretorio.gridy = 4;
        gbc_campo_preencher_diretorio.gridheight = 1;
        gbc_descricao_software.gridwidth = 1;
        contentPane.add(campo_preencher_diretorio, gbc_campo_preencher_diretorio);
        campo_preencher_diretorio.setColumns(20);

        JButton botao_selecionar_pasta_projeto = new JButton("...");
        botao_selecionar_pasta_projeto.setAction(acaoSelecionarPastaProjeto);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_botao_selecionar_pasta_projeto = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_botao_selecionar_pasta_projeto.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_botao_selecionar_pasta_projeto.gridx = 2;
        gbc_botao_selecionar_pasta_projeto.gridy = 4;
        gbc_botao_selecionar_pasta_projeto.gridheight = 1;
        contentPane.add(botao_selecionar_pasta_projeto, gbc_botao_selecionar_pasta_projeto);

        JButton botao_explicacao_selecione_diretorio = new JButton("?");
        botao_explicacao_selecione_diretorio.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        botao_explicacao_selecione_diretorio.setToolTipText("escolha a pasta raiz do seu projeto");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_botao_explicacao_selecione_diretorio = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_botao_explicacao_selecione_diretorio.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_botao_explicacao_selecione_diretorio.gridx = 3;
        gbc_botao_explicacao_selecione_diretorio.gridy = 4;
        gbc_botao_explicacao_selecione_diretorio.gridheight = 1;
        contentPane.add(botao_explicacao_selecione_diretorio, gbc_botao_explicacao_selecione_diretorio);

        //PARTE REFERENTE A ADICIONAR EXTENSÃO(ANDREWS)
        JPanel painel_adicionar_extensao = new JPanel();
        TitledBorder tituloPainelExtensoes;
        tituloPainelExtensoes = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Extensões");
        painel_adicionar_extensao.setBorder(tituloPainelExtensoes);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_painel_adicionar_extensao = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_painel_adicionar_extensao.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_painel_adicionar_extensao.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gbc_painel_adicionar_extensao.gridheight = 7;
        gbc_painel_adicionar_extensao.gridx = 4;
        gbc_painel_adicionar_extensao.gridy = 3;
        gbc_painel_adicionar_extensao.gridwidth = 4;
        contentPane.add(painel_adicionar_extensao, gbc_painel_adicionar_extensao);
        GridBagLayout gbl_painel_adicionar_extensao = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_painel_adicionar_extensao.columnWidths = new int[]{20, 20, 20, 20};
        gbl_painel_adicionar_extensao.rowHeights = new int[]{20, 20, 20, 20};
        gbl_painel_adicionar_extensao.columnWeights = new double[]{0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4};
        gbl_painel_adicionar_extensao.rowWeights = new double[]{0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4};
        painel_adicionar_extensao.setLayout(gbl_painel_adicionar_extensao);



        textFieldAdicionarExtensoes = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldAdicionarExtensoes = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textFieldAdicionarExtensoes.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc_textFieldAdicionarExtensoes.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_textFieldAdicionarExtensoes.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textFieldAdicionarExtensoes.gridx = 0;
        gbc_textFieldAdicionarExtensoes.gridy = 3;
        painel_adicionar_extensao.add(textFieldAdicionarExtensoes, gbc_textFieldAdicionarExtensoes);
        textFieldAdicionarExtensoes.setColumns(10);

        buttonRemoverExtensoes = new JButton("-");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_buttonRemoverExtensoes = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_buttonRemoverExtensoes.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_buttonRemoverExtensoes.gridx = 3;
        gbc_buttonRemoverExtensoes.gridy = 0;
        painel_adicionar_extensao.add(buttonRemoverExtensoes, gbc_buttonRemoverExtensoes);
        buttonRemoverExtensoes.addActionListener(this);

        this.listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        this.listaExtensoes = new JList<String>(listModel);

        GridBagConstraints gbc_listaExtensoes = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_listaExtensoes.gridheight = 3;
        gbc_listaExtensoes.gridwidth = 4;
        gbc_listaExtensoes.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 25);
        gbc_listaExtensoes.gridx = 0;
        gbc_listaExtensoes.gridy = 0;
        listaExtensoes.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        listaExtensoes.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        listaExtensoes.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(listaExtensoes);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 120));
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel = listaExtensoes.getSelectionModel();
        listSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(
                                new ListenerListaExtensoes(buttonRemoverExtensoes,listaExtensoes));

        painel_adicionar_extensao.add(scrollPane, gbc_listaExtensoes);

        buttonAdicionarExtensoes = new JButton("+");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_buttonAdicionarExtensoes = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_buttonAdicionarExtensoes.gridx = 3;
        gbc_buttonAdicionarExtensoes.gridy = 3;
        painel_adicionar_extensao.add(buttonAdicionarExtensoes, gbc_buttonAdicionarExtensoes);
        buttonAdicionarExtensoes.addActionListener(this);
        extensoes= new LinkedList<String>();



        JLabel label_autor = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createLabel("Autor:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label_autor = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label_autor.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_label_autor.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_label_autor.gridx = 0;
        gbc_label_autor.gridy = 5;
        gbc_label_autor.gridheight = 1;
        contentPane.add(label_autor, gbc_label_autor);

        campo_preencher_autor = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_campo_preencher_autor = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_campo_preencher_autor.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_campo_preencher_autor.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_campo_preencher_autor.gridx = 1;
        gbc_campo_preencher_autor.gridy = 5;
        gbc_campo_preencher_autor.gridheight = 1;
        contentPane.add(campo_preencher_autor, gbc_campo_preencher_autor);
        campo_preencher_autor.setColumns(20);

        JLabel label_versao = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createLabel("Vers\u00E3o:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label_versao = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label_versao.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_label_versao.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_label_versao.gridx = 0;
        gbc_label_versao.gridy = 6;
        gbc_label_versao.gridheight = 1;
        contentPane.add(label_versao, gbc_label_versao);

        campo_preencher_versao = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_campo_preencher_versao = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_campo_preencher_versao.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_campo_preencher_versao.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_campo_preencher_versao.gridx = 1;
        gbc_campo_preencher_versao.gridy = 6;
        contentPane.add(campo_preencher_versao, gbc_campo_preencher_versao);
        gbc_campo_preencher_versao.gridheight = 1;
        campo_preencher_versao.setColumns(10);

        JLabel label_output = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createLabel("Output:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label_output = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label_output.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_label_output.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_label_output.gridx = 0;
        gbc_label_output.gridy = 7;
        gbc_label_output.gridheight = 1;
        contentPane.add(label_output, gbc_label_output);

        campo_preencher_output = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_campo_preencher_output = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_campo_preencher_output.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_campo_preencher_output.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_campo_preencher_output.gridx = 1;
        gbc_campo_preencher_output.gridy = 7;
        gbc_campo_preencher_output.gridheight = 1;
        contentPane.add(campo_preencher_output, gbc_campo_preencher_output);
        campo_preencher_output.setColumns(10);

        JButton botao_especificar_arquivo_output = new JButton("...");
        botao_especificar_arquivo_output.setAction(acaoEspecificarOutput);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_botao_especificar_arquivo_output = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_botao_especificar_arquivo_output.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_botao_especificar_arquivo_output.gridx = 2;
        gbc_botao_especificar_arquivo_output.gridy = 7;
        gbc_botao_especificar_arquivo_output.gridheight = 1;
        contentPane.add(botao_especificar_arquivo_output, gbc_botao_especificar_arquivo_output);

        JButton botaoEspecificarPastas = new JButton("Avançado...");
        botaoEspecificarPastas.setAction(acaoBotaoEspecificarPastasArquivosProjeto);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_botaoEspecificarPastas = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_botaoEspecificarPastas.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_botaoEspecificarPastas.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_botaoEspecificarPastas.gridx = 1;
        gbc_botaoEspecificarPastas.gridy = 8;
        contentPane.add(botaoEspecificarPastas, gbc_botaoEspecificarPastas);

        JButton botao_explicacao_especificar_pastas = new JButton("?");
        botao_explicacao_especificar_pastas.setToolTipText("especificar que pastas/arquivos de seu projeto você quer no PDF");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_botao_explicacao_especificar_pastas = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_botao_explicacao_especificar_pastas.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_botao_explicacao_especificar_pastas.gridx = 2;
        gbc_botao_explicacao_especificar_pastas.gridy = 8;
        contentPane.add(botao_explicacao_especificar_pastas, gbc_botao_explicacao_especificar_pastas);

        JButton botaoGerarPDF = new JButton("Gerar PDF");
        botaoGerarPDF.setAction(acaoGerarPdf);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_botaoGerarPDF = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_botaoGerarPDF.gridheight = 3;
        gbc_botaoGerarPDF.gridwidth = 2;
        //gbc_botaoGerarPDF.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_botaoGerarPDF.gridx = 1;
        gbc_botaoGerarPDF.gridy = 9;
        contentPane.add(botaoGerarPDF, gbc_botaoGerarPDF);

        JProgressBar barraDeProgresso = new JProgressBar();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_JProgressBarUsuarioClicouNoBotaoAvancado = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_JProgressBarUsuarioClicouNoBotaoAvancado.gridheight = 1;
        gbc_JProgressBarUsuarioClicouNoBotaoAvancado.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_JProgressBarUsuarioClicouNoBotaoAvancado.gridx = 1;
        gbc_JProgressBarUsuarioClicouNoBotaoAvancado.gridy = 10;
        contentPane.add(barraDeProgresso, gbc_JProgressBarUsuarioClicouNoBotaoAvancado);
        SingletonBarraDeProgresso.getInstance().setBarraDeProgresso(barraDeProgresso);

        textoBarraDeProgresso = new JLabel("oi meu nome é andrews e eu sou uma pessoa legal como vocês são e eu falo muito não é vamos falar mais um pouco");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textoBarraDeProgresso = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textoBarraDeProgresso.gridheight = 1;
        gbc_textoBarraDeProgresso.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_textoBarraDeProgresso.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textoBarraDeProgresso.gridy = 11;
        contentPane.add(textoBarraDeProgresso, gbc_textoBarraDeProgresso);
        textoBarraDeProgresso.setText("oi meu nome é andrews");
        textoBarraDeProgresso.setVisible(true);
        SingletonBarraDeProgresso.getInstance().setTextoBarraDeProgresso(textoBarraDeProgresso);

        SingletonBarraDeProgresso.getInstance().setTelaPrincipal(this);

        extensoes= new LinkedList<String>();

        //vamos verificar se n jah existem extensoes no arquivo .txt que podemos usar
        this.verificarSeJaExistemExtensoesNoTxtParaJaPovoarAGuiComEstasExtensoes();
    }
```

But when i try to change it via my Singleton on this method:

```
public void inicializarBarraDeProgresso(int valorMaximo, String textoBarra)
    {
        if(barraDeProgresso != null)
        {
            barraDeProgresso.setVisible(true);
            barraDeProgresso.setStringPainted(true);
            barraDeProgresso.setValue(0);
            this.barraDeProgresso.setMaximum(valorMaximo);
            this.barraDeProgresso.setMinimum(0);

            this.textoBarraDeProgresso.setVisible(true);
            this.textoBarraDeProgresso.setText(textoBarra);

        }
    }
```

Which is called inside many classes(TelaPrincipal is one of them, but there are a lot of other classes), the text stays the same: "oi meu nome é andrews"

I have also tried myJLabel.update(myJLabel.getGraphics()); after the setText(), but it bugs by text(it´s like it creates a loop which puts a lot of text over each other).

Comment: Don't ever use update(...). That is a method used internally when a component needs to be repainted. All you need to do is invoke the setText() method of the label. If it doesn't work, then it means you don't have a reference to the label. Maybe you defined the variable twice, once as an instance variable and once as a local variable. Get rid of the local variable. If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I just created the JLabel once, but i pass the object to my Singleton, so it can call the setText()... Does this mean defining it twice?

Comment: No. As long as you only invoke the "new JLabel(...)` statement once you only have one label but who knows what you are really doing. Maybe the class that creates the label is created twice so in reality you do have two labels. I don't know why you are using a Singleton. Anyway you have been asked to post a `SSCCE`.

Comment: i have posted some code. Not the entire Singleton and TelaInicial because they are really big, but just the part of them which uses the JLabel

Comment: @user2997681 Please read up on what an `SSCCE` is. What you posted is neither small, nor self contained, or even a good example (I have no clue how exactly what this code does differs from the intention). Don't take this the wrong way, but this will simplify things for everyone, and chances are that after you take away the "irrelevant" bits from your example it will suddenly start to work, pointing you in the direction of the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

This post is the real lifesaver:

[Why isn't setText updating the JLabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536390/why-isnt-settext-updating-the-jlabel)

Basically, all you have to do is:

```
label.paintImmediately(label.getVisibleRect());
```

Right after the settext().

Java swing is confusing and annoying. I really do like working with android better ^^

Comment: You shouldn't have to call paintImmediately(). On the other hand, you SHOULD be calling inicializarBarraDeProgresso() from the EventThread; calling it from any other thread will not necessarily cause the updates to be visible..